# Openapi - Api-First approach and third-party classes as response

Tags: java, api, openapi

Let's assume I want to follow the API-first approach with openapi. The response of an endpoint should be a JSON of Java objects whose classes are implemented in a third-party library. Thus, they already exist and are not under my control.

What is the best option here to specify the API?

- Define a new DTO type in my openapi spec and implement a mapper from existing class to generated DTO class? Feels like boilerplate code.
- define the response to be a string and mention in the description that the String encodes a JSON of an existing-class object. This would cleary generate ugly code.

There isn't a way to reference existing Java classes in the spec file, I guess.

Comment: I think the first solution its the best in your case. I mean, by desing the third-party library with your objects are outside of your domain, so not a boilerplate if you have your own DTO in your domain, casually its the same object in terms of fields and behavior, but the difference its is in your domain and you have the control.